# How do I restrict access to a specific URL?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to restrict access to a specific URL with `.htaccess`. I want to do this because the PHP/html file on the specific URL doesn't work as it should since the URL is wrong.

I don't want anyone to be able to access this URL:

```
example.com/folder/file.php/*
```

but I want everyone to be able to access

```
example.com/folder/file.php
```

and

```
example.com/folder/*.php/*
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)file.php/(.*)$ [OR]`

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to just need a single `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) directive:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder/file.php/ - [F]
```

This blocks (403 Forbidden) access to `/folder/file.php/<anything>` (where `/<anything>` is path-info). It does not match requests of the form `/folder/file.php` or `/folder/*.php/*` - so these requests are still *allowed*.

Any blocking directives like this should be at the start of the `.htaccess` file.